# express function and variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, variables, express

I am trying to créate a function who have a variable in atribute, if the var exists return the variable else return the var name

```
app.locals.test = function(myvar){
    if ( typeof(myvar) != "undefined" ) {
        return myvar
    }
    return 'false'
}
```

I have no problem il the var is defined but fi the var is no defined I have testVar is not defined. And I don't haw to get the var name

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm just curious... Even if you'd get this work, how would you actually handle the return value? I mean, how can you know if the returned value was a variable name or an actual value of the variable? Actually it's not possible to get the original name of the variable passed to the function, so we'd like to see the code you have before calling this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function testVar(variable) {
    if (!variable) return 'UNDEFINED VARIABLE';
    return variable;
}
```

But I can't get the var name with javascript

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question correct... you wish to return the name of the variable which in the function is locally known as "myvar". So if the above code works then ...the solution can be :

```
app.locals.test = function(myvar){
    if ( typeof(myvar) != "undefined" ) {
        return myvar;
    } else {
       return 'myvar';
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't wan to return myvar, I just want to return the name of the var if it not defined, for exemple test(undefinedVar) => undefinedvar

Comment: That is what is happening ....inside else its return "myvar", ie when it is not defined it will return the string "myvar". But when it is defined the value of myvar is returned as there are no "" in this return. Also, if you to display the name of the variable as it was when it was passed to the function then you will have to save it in a variable inside the function that called test function and also pass it to test so that test can return it when required.

Comment: The called function has no knowledge of the variables that are not local to it.So you need to have a variable to store the name of the var too. I guess it should be easy if you are hard coding the names of the var.

Comment: nop, if I try the function I'll have undefined var myvar if myvar is not defined